# Adding a custom prop to a component in react

Tags: reactjs

This library https://github.com/feathericons/react-feather/issues/41 use a different way to reference icons I am looking to configure that progrimatically, I tried adding the solution right there but I got this error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I am not sure how do I reference the name of the Icon, the regular import looks like

```
import { Camera } from 'react-feather';

const App = () => {
  return <Camera />
};
```

But to import all it uses this way that not works for me

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Icon from 'react-feather';

const App = () => {
  return <Icon.Camera />
};
```

I tried import all like

```
import * as Feather from 'react-feather'
```

then I assumed I should reference the `const` after render, I also tried before `Component`

```
render () {
    let {
      loading,
      selectedIcon
    } = this.state

    const FeatherIcon = Feather[this.props.name]
```

It crash here

```
return (
  <Container className='masterdiv'>
    <div className='mb center'>
     <FeatherIcon name='Camera' color='black' size={20} />
   ...
```

I am not sure how do I access the props that I set named `name`

Comment: try a null check in your render function.- make sure your name isn't null. Do 
`render () {
    let {
      loading,
      selectedIcon
    } = this.state
   if (!this.props.name) return null;
   const FeatherIcon = Feather[this.props.name]`

Comment: You're saying `import { Camera } from 'react-feather';` works but not `import * as Icon from 'react-feather'; Icon.Camera`?

Answer (score 0):

For typeScript I used it

```
import React from 'react';
import * as icons from 'react-feather';

export type IconName = keyof typeof icons;

export type IconProps = {
  name: IconName;
  color?: string;
  size?: string | number;
};

export const Icons = ({ name, ...rest }: IconProps) => {
  const IconComponent = icons[name];
  return <IconComponent {...rest} />;
};
```

based on this post:
[Add icon name prop](https://github.com/feathericons/react-feather/issues/41)

by the user @kraenhansen